# PHP Regex: Replace string with array of words which must starts and ends with hyphens or spaces

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace/remove array of words from string .. And this words must starts with and ends with hyphens `-in-` or whitspaces `in`

This is what I've tried so far

```
$string = 'inline things in inline workin workin AND inline-things-in-inline-workin-workin فيلا فيلا في انفيلا انفي انفي AND فيلا-فيلا-في-انفيلا-انفي-انفي';
$array_of_words = ['in' , 'في' , 'فى'];
// I tried
echo _remove_words($string , $array_of_words);
function _remove_words($string , $array_of_words){
  $string = preg_replace('/(?<=^|[^\p{L}])' . implode('|',$array_of_words) . '(?=[^\p{L}]|$)/ui','',$string);
  return $string;
}
```

The expected output should remove `in` , `في`, `-in-` , `-في-` from the string to be

`inline things inline workin workin AND inline-things-inline-workin-workin فيلا فيلا انفيلا انفي انفي AND فيلا-فيلا انفيلا-انفي-انفي`

I also tried

```
'/#-' . implode('|',$array_of_words) . '-#/ui'
'/^-' . implode('|',$array_of_words) . '-$/ui'
```

So I think I'll separate the patterns one to replace the whitespaces `in` , `في` with space and another one to replace `-in-` , `-في-` with hyphen

Thanks in advance

Comment: First thing I see: the result of your `implode` needs  to have () around the resuklt. You need brackets with |: `(string1|string2)`

Comment: @Roemer No need for second thing because the First thing is totally enough .. everythings works fine after I added `( )` .. Thanks A ton

Comment: Can one of you turn the comment into an answer?

Comment: Don't forget to `preg_quote()` the words.